# Need help looping

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing an assignment for class where you gather the salary of your employees and I have become stumped. It keeps continuously looping the ""What is their salary: "" part so how can I fix it to where the salary matches up with the employee, instead of it keep on asking what the salary is?  This is what I have so far please help me out with any tips advice. **(I am not asking for you to do my work. I just want some tips/advice)**

```
def main():
    name = []
    salary = []
    n = 0
    n = int(input("How many employee's will you be entering?: "))
    for i in range(n):
         name = input("Enter the employees name: ")
    empsalary(name,salary)

def empsalary(empname,esalary):
    salary = 0
    salary = int(input("What is their salary: "))
    for i in range(salary):
        if salary < 1 or salary > 200000:
            salary = int(input("What is their salary: "))
        if salary > 0 and salary < 200000:
            salary = int(input("What is their salary: "))
```

Answer (score 1):

This line does not do what you think it does:

```
for i in range(salary):
```

This will iterate `salary` times, sequentially assigning `i` the values `0` to `salary-1`.

That is why it keeps looping over the input in the body of that loop. It also doesn't matter if you change `salary` in the body, because `range(salary)` is evaluated on entry to the loop, and evaluates to a list containing the numbers which will be assigned to `i`.

Update:

Also, there is no value of `salary` that will not trigger one of these if clauses;

```
    if salary < 1 or salary > 200000:
        salary = int(input("What is their salary: "))
    if salary > 0 and salary < 200000:
        salary = int(input("What is their salary: "))
```

Update 2:

Look at this code:

```
for i in range(n):
     name = input("Enter the employees name: ")
empsalary(name,salary)
```

You call `empsalary` only once, after asking for all employee names. I can tell this is not what you want.

Update 3: I also note that you don't actually do anything with the `name`s you capture. You just overwrite them in the next iteration. Don't do that, store them.

Update 4: You also don't do anything with the `salary`s , and you don't actually return anything from your function.

Comment: So, I shouldn't use the "for" loop? And I just figured it would work cuz this part that I did worked. for i in range(n):
         name = input("Enter the employees name: ")

Comment: I don't follow your reasoning. Use a `while` loop with a condition to test if salary is unacceptable.

Comment: I saw your updated part and I put "salary = 0" and would while empsalary = salary work?

Comment: @ThatOneDude No. Why would it? Think about what the purpose of the loop is.

Comment: I really suck wiht this stuff. But I figured it would work because the empsalary and salary are part of the same thing. So I figured since they are they must be able to = each other.

Comment: @ThatOneDude What would that accomplish? *Why are you running the loop?*

Comment: I'm running the loop so I could find the average salaries of all employees that were entered and to find the ones with the highest and lowest salaries.

Comment: @ThatOneDude No you're not. That's what you're trying to accomplish in the programme as a whole. What is the purpose of repeating the body of the loop? Why would you want to run it more than once?

Comment: I wouldn't. That is what I am trying to fix.

Comment: @ThatOneDude No, you do need to run that body more than once. If you don't want to run it more than once, you would not have a loop at all.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try something more like this:

```
def main():
    name = []
    salary = []

    n = 0
    n = int(input("How many employee's will you be entering?: "))

    for i in range(n):
         name.append( input("Enter the employees name: ") )
         salary.append( int(input("What is their salary: ")) )

    print_high_and_low(name, salary)

def print_high_and_low(name, salary):
    """Find maximum and minimum salaries"""
    # find maximum salary
    max = 0
    for i in range(len(salary)):
        if salary[i] > max:
            max = salary[i]
            max_index = i

    # find minimum salary
    min = 9999999  # Smarter would be: sys.maxint (if you import sys)
    for i in range(len(salary)):
        if salary[i] < min:
            min = salary[i]
            min_index = i

    print name[max_index] + " has the highest salary of: " + str(max)
    print name[min_index] + " has the lowest salary of: " + str(min)
```

Notice that I did not need the `empsalary` method.

**Issues with the original version**:

1. In your `empsalary` method your loop `for i in range(salary)` loops over the SALARY of your latest employee. I think you want to loop over the NUMBER of employees.  Can you see that is what I did?
2. Those if-statements of yours will never trigger to do anything particularly interesting. What was your goal for those two if-statements?
3. You set up `name` and `salary` as lists, but you weren't treating them like lists. In this version you will save all the data entered in two lists for later use (finding the max and min salaries).

Comment: This solves the problem, but does not explain what is specifically wrong with OP's code.

Comment: I would have done that but sadly, my teacher said we need to have use the "def" module functions for this.

Comment: @ThatOneDude Where does the phrase "def module functions" come from? It's not correct.

Comment: Well I am going to use them to find the employee who had the highest and lowest.

Comment: @ThatOneDude I have also added a method to find the highest and lowest salary.  There are more concise ways to do this, but I think this is the easiest to read and understand.

Comment: You'll note that this doesn't comport with the requirements mentioned in comments on other answers, because the requirements are to ask for all names before all salaries. I think you or I may be a better teacher than OP's.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks. That helps. I hope I will eventually be able to understand Python and know how to do it :P

Comment: @ThatOneDude Your problem is not that you don't understand python. It's that you fundamentally don't understand what you are trying to accomplish. That is why you are flailing about and guessing. You need to be able to articulate the purpose of every single piece of your programme.

Comment: I don't mean to guess and flail. I try trial and error and I just guess.

Comment: @ThatOneDude Trial and error is fine if you know what you are trying to do. However, you must actually know what the purpose of the code is before you write it. I strongly suggest that you go through each piece of your code, and write a comment explaining to yourself why you wrote that code.

Comment: I should start doing that. I tend to just ignore commenting. But I'll start doing that from now on. That might make things easier.

Comment: @ThatOneDude Try writing the comment before you write the code. Then write code which fulfills that purpose. You can try and try again until that purpose is fulfilled, or you realise that the purpose is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert in Python, but I think I see what your problem is.

According to your code here, you're asking the user for a number of any size. Once they've input this number, then program proceeds to execute a FOR loop [salary] number of times. This can be a problem if you've made the employee's salary something huge like 10,000, as this will cause the loop to execute 10,000 times!

I'm guessing that you're trying to make sure that the salary is somewhere between 0 and 200,000 and if the salary falls outside of this range, then the program will continue to ask for a salary. If this is indeed the case, a while loop should do the trick while eliminating a couple lines of code.

```
def empsalary(empname,esalary):
   salary = 0
   salary = int(input("What is their salary: "))
   while (salary < 1 or salary > 200000):
       salary = int(input("What is their salary: "))
```

This should do what you need. Good luck on your assignment!